# How to pass Object Fields as Function Parameters (feature vector)

Tags: c++

I want to write a function where i pass it two objects and a array of their fields as parameters to calculate a measure of simmilarity.

Say i have two objects A and B and they have fields like A.size, A.weight, A.color, A.id.

Now i want a function that gets and array of size 2 with these parameters, so it would look something like this:

```
double measureSim (Car a, Car b, ??? feature[2]){

 double value = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < feature.size; i++){
    double += (A.feature[i] - B.feature[i]);
 }

return value
}
```

I hope you can understand what i am trying to say.

EDIT: the point is to make a function that can compare arbitrary fileds of two objects. For example when clustering. I want to be able to tell the function what fields to take into account.

Comment: If you have objects, why passing their members as parameters seperately. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean an array of pointers to member variables.. but it would make little sense to me..

Comment: @Mahesh: He doesn't necessarily want _all_ members to be considered on each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to pass some kind of "reference to <strike>field</strike> member name" array and iterate over a class in that way, then you're not going to be able to do it in this way. You can't loop over the *members* of a type.

You could pass an array of pointers-to-member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// (all doubles for exposition)
struct Car
{
    double size;
    double weight;
    double color;
    double id;
};

typedef double Car::*ptrToCarMember;

double measureSim(const Car& a, const Car& b, std::vector<ptrToCarMember> feature)
{
    double value = 0;

    for (auto el : feature) {
        value += a.*el - b.*el;
    }

    return value;
}

int main()
{
    Car a = { 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0 };
    Car b = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };

    {
        std::vector<ptrToCarMember> features{&Car::size};
        std::cout << measureSim(a, b, features) << '\n';
    }

    {
        std::vector<ptrToCarMember> features{&Car::id};
        std::cout << measureSim(a, b, features) << '\n';
    }

    {
        std::vector<ptrToCarMember> features{&Car::size, &Car::weight, &Car::color};
        std::cout << measureSim(a, b, features) << '\n';
    }
}

// $ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall main.cpp && ./a.out
// 0
// 4
// 1
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faa8e2f004140697))

But, yikes! It is very rare to find a need for pointers-to-members. Maybe you've found a good reason. Just be sure to well document your need and your code. Also note that all the members you want to use in this way will have to have the same type (here it's `double`); you can't mix and match.

It would probably be more idiomatic to use variadic templates, but I'm not going to go into that here as it is an advanced topic and likely overkill for this.

You could also look at simply replacing your member variables with a `std::map` and then you can do lots of stuff with the map's keys and values with no need for "magic".

Comment: could you please be a little more explaining about this one ? How would it be possible what you have suggested and why is it a bad idea ?

Comment: @user2664856: Like this? :)

Comment: yes, thank you. Do you understand my problem ? I want to specify which members to take into account when clustering. So i need a measure of similarity between two samples. Do you know a better way to solve this problem ? Or should i ask a new question on this one ?

Comment: @user2664856: I suggest a few ideas at the end of the answer. Ultimately, a broader exploration of your options would depend on what the rest of your code looks like, what your constraints are, what your requirements are, and all sorts of other things that would take a sit-down meeting with a consultant for an hour to figure out.

Comment: last question: as it seems not to be an absurde question and not easy to answer as well ... why did i get downvoted ?

Comment: @user2664856: Probably because your formatting is a bit weird, you didn't explain yourself well, you didn't provide evidence of any research, and your terminology is off ("fields"?). It also wasn't entirely clear on the first read what you were really asking. Lucky for you, Quentin and I are unparalleled geniuses. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your fields are of the same type (say, `float`), you are looking for *pointer-to-members*. The syntax is as follows :

```
// An example class with two fields to choose from
class A {
    float f1;
    float f2;
};

int main(int, char**) {

    // Declaration of a pointer-to-member
    float A::*ptr;

    // Assignment, note that we don't have an instance yet
    ptr = &A::f1;

    // Creating an actual instance
    A a;

    // Using the pointer on the instance
    a.*ptr = 3.14f;

    // Check that it worked. It did !
    std::cout << a.f1 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

You'd want to pass an array of these.

If they are *not* all of the same type, you'll need something way more involved, with template-flavored type erasure.

Comment: can you maybe explain an easier way to tell a function which members to take into account when clustering for example ?

Comment: @user2664856 that's building your array on the caller's side before passing it to the function. You may want to search for it, it has probably been asked already.

Comment: @user2664856: I demonstrate that in my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit are you taking my business away ? :p

Comment: @Quentin: It's a cold world, and I have mouths to feed!